# What is the best liquid level sensor

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

I need a sensor for measuring level of liquid in a tank. The method of measuring should be non contact type. Please give any suggestion. I want to interface the sensor with a microcontroller like STM32 or AVR.

Tank diameter is 2m and depth is 5m. The liquid inside is industrial coolant. Use will be indoors. Continuous measurements is needed and three switches are required to be activated depending upon the level.

I am interested in the following sensor. MB1000 LV-MaxSonar-EZ0 or MB1010 LV-MaxSonar-EZ1. Please suggest.

Comment: There are many possible types of sensors as even a rudimentary search will find. Not surprisingly, the optimum sensor will depend on the situation- the sensor for a water tank in an ultrasonic humidifier will likely be different from sensors used in a hydrocarbon tank farm.

Comment: What is the tank size , fluid and tank material?

Comment: You also need to specify if you are interested in continuous level measurement or if low/mid/high level sensors are enough.

Comment: Down vote for the lack of important details and specific application scenario.

Comment: Asking for "the best" is "silly". I could recommend the UltraGauger 2100 which has better specifications than all other sensors but if you have to ask what it costs you cannot afford it. Oh, I made this up just as an example, the UltraGauger 2100 does not exist. Saying that cost and accuracy need to be "moderate" is pointless, what is "moderate"? Google "level gauging" and see what you get. Normal prices are easily in the range of $ 1000 or more for radar based gauges.

Comment: @Rhony: All the information you have added belongs in the question and not buried in the comments. Use the edit link below the question and write a proper specification. Please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: WHy not 4 levels like FIFO's? Empty, Almost Empty, Almost Full, Full

Comment: Use a floating sensor like fuel car tanks, if is too high for that float then use several floats

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that questions about optimization (i.e., *"What is the best ...?"*) require a definition about what problem dimensions are to be optimized for your application, such as size, speed, energy consumption, user experience, etc. Since these can't be optimized all at once, you need to have a good idea of which ones are most important to you, and be able to articulate that clearly to us.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution always comes from the best specs;

```
 Budget
 Accuracy
 Environment 
 Fluid
 Tank material and size
```

The main choices are;

1. Non-Contact Ultrasonic Sensors with temp. compensation and serial ports
2. PTFE coated Capacitance Level Sensors
3. Radar Level transponders

Comment: I am interested in ultrasonic solution.Cost and accuracy should be moderate.

Comment: I need to know about maxbotics ultra sonic sensor. Any suggestions..

Comment: Tank material is concrete.

Comment: Budget might be the last on the list instead of first...

Comment: I'm not a sensor salesman, do your homework

Comment: Don't forget to add drift. A glass of water with shaved ice has some nice initial accuracy on temperature. Of course, give it a day. It's definitely drifted some. Also, I can't count the number of times someone has come up with a fantastic idea, only to find that when tested in practice we find it's actually much better at detecting whether or not the building's air conditioner is on than it is for its design purpose. And then there's the question if this is liquid hydrogen or liquid boiling sulfuric acid to be measured.

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of sensor available with different principle, accuracy and precision & it can also work with microcontroller

You have to choose upon your requirement like budget, accuracy, power source,etc.

some of sensors are listed here..

Ultrasonic sensor good for hobby project and can work with AVR and also range up to 2m

water level sensor but not for long range

float switches , switch the NO to close or vice versa when required height of water is reached

and other are capacitance level sensor, infrared , multiple wire type etc.

Comment: Please provide links to the images you inserted in your question, or at least a citation of the source.

Comment: please read fully code of  conduct before making any comment @ElliotAlderson

Comment: Please read the site policies about providing proper references to material you use: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing